# den or dem? Doubt about use of accusative or dative

Tags: accusative

Why is it correct the phrase: "Wie wichtig ist den Deutschen dieser Sport" and not "Wie wichtig ist dem Deutschen dieser Sport"?

Answer (score 8):

Both is correct; but your assumption about accusative is wrong.

It is dative in both cases. "*den Deutschen*" is dative of plural "*die Deutschen*". So the first sentence is translated as "How important is this sport for the Germans (for German people)?"

In the second sentence you talk about a single male person or about a prototypical German regardless of genders (so in the same meaning as the plural) - *How important is this sport for the German?* 
There are not so many situations where you could use this sentence but still it is correct.

Comment: I partly disagree with the last paragraph. It does not necessarily refer to only males but could be used to refer to a prototypical German no matter the gender. It has to be clear from the context though, that you are talking about Germans in general. Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: @problemofficer Yes, you're right. I added this.

Comment: I took the liberty to propose an edit to specifically mention the genders to make the explanation clearer. I also removed the reference to me. Thank you, but it decreases readability.